# How to login by text mode with LinuxMint 17.3?

Tags: linux-mint, runlevel

I have a problem for to login `LinuxMint 17.3`, and want to login in text mode.
But I couln't find where can I change runlevel.

This is the login screen. I'm running LinuxMint in Virtualbox environment.

[image]

How can I login as a text mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not switch to text console using the `control-alt f1/f2/....` keys combinations ?

Comment: Because I didn't know that key bind. Thanks!

Comment: the `f8` is for going back to graphical environment, if needed :)